# When you use this plugin you must install `typescript`. error

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I am using yarn 2 and react with webpack.

In my package is `"typescript": ...` defined. Once I start `yarn start` I am getting an error:

```
yarn workspace test start
When you use this plugin you must install `typescript`.
```

What is wrong? How should I fix it? Or debug it?

Comment: have the same issue, but I have only for the dev-server project where I use custom webpack config.. for the main nx project it build fine

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the similar issue when I was upgrading webpack from 4 to 5.
The problem was the version of react-dev-utils

Upgrading react-dev-utils from v10 to v12 made the issue disappear.

```
devDependencies {
...
 "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be checked the value of your plugins config about `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin` which the param key named `tsconfig`.

1. `Error Message`

[image: My Error message]

2. Check `[key, value]` about `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`.

[image: webpack.config.js plugins config]

3. Find it in your node_modules, and set debug point, run the debugger.

[image: Debug Point]

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at your webpack.config.js where ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin is initialized. ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin needs to be able to find the tsconfig file.

```
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
    typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
      basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
      tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
    })
  }),
```

In my case I'm defining paths.appNodeModules and paths.appsTsConfig in a file called paths.js.

```
module.exports = {
    appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
    appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue and I solved it by upgrading my dependencies. You can use VS Code extension to check which dependency needs to be updated.